# Overriding in module not working in prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop and developing a module to change behaviour of checkout process. As i am new, i am first overriding IndexController.php file in my module directory to just test the overriding mechanism in prestashop. The directory structure, i have followed, to override controller file as:

```
modules/my_modules/override/controllers/front/IndexController.php
```

Below is the code of above file:

```
class IndexController extends IndexControllerCore{

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    d('You are overriding index file');
  }    
}
```

In above code, i have just created an construct and print a test string with die. But nothing is happening on the home page on front end. I have also tried with override another controller file, but i have got same result.

I have searched many things on google, but nothing got. Please anyone tell me, what i am doing wrong in this? if the logic is correct, then why overriding is not working here?

Waiting for solution.

Comment: Did you reinstall the module after adding the override?

Comment: Thanks for reply! No, i have not reinstall module after override.

Comment: Then you should do it :)

Comment: And remove cache file: cache/class_index.php

Answer (score 1):

Like @rsanchez said. You need to reinstall the module everytime you change your module's overrides. Prestashop will not automatically check for new changes or new overrides without it.